# Regex to match <%= server tag in a text to protect from injection

Tags: c#, regex, .net-4.5, code-behind

```
  Regex r = new Regex("([sS][cC][rR][iI][pP][tT])|([sS][qQ][lL])|(<%=)");
```

doesnt find any <%= occurences but finds SqL, SQL, sQL, script, ScRipT, ... correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

```
  [\<]  gives escape unrecognized error. Just as [\%] do.
```

Example string:

```
   Injection protection test:
   <script> alert('fail'); 
   </script> 
   <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
   <%= Server.Rewrite( ....) %>
```

Comment: might i suggest using an case insensitive regex?

Comment: Tried [\<] and this gives escape unrecognized error.

Comment: Seems fine. I guess you'd need to post the string you're testing and also @DanielA.White's suggestion will save you a lot of needless repetition.

Comment: can you show the text in which you want to find your regex?

Comment: As @DanielA.White suggested, with case-insensitivity it looks much nicer: `script|sql|<%=`

Comment: When you want to use a backslash in your regex string, either write the string like `"some\\thing"`, or `@"some\thing"` (note that @ symbol at the second string)

Comment: @elgonzo While correct, none of the characters in question require escaping afaik.

Comment: @RGraham, yes, you are ofcourse right. My comment was only about the "escape unrecognized error" (i should have said that in my comment...)

Comment: I don't see any `<%=` in the example string.

Comment: you can use this page: http://www.regexr.com/ to test your regex

Comment: It searches for `<%=` as well with your regex pattern. Test it [here](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx)

Comment: Please don't reinvent the wheel poorly. This code isn't going to make your site any safer, and it will prevent anyone from using the perfectly legitimate words "script" and "SQL". Explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Braj But doesnt work for .Net 4.5 C# codebehind Regex() instance. :(

Comment: There are ways of performing scripting attacks that do not involve the single entire word `SCRIPT` (in any case sensitivity). IMO, you are approaching this entirely from the wrong angle. You should be *escaping data at output*. Attempting to filter input is just an arms race.

Comment: Now, if only asp.net had ouput escaping built in... for example if only `<%:expression %>` existed...

Comment: if you are just wanting to sanitize the input and make sure that it is not dangerous you could use something like this http://www.github.com/websey it is a class that takes a string and processes it against the enum and if it is dangerous returns false which you can then use to do something with the string, you could also extend the enum list to include extra things that you want to sanitize

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Approaching the problem from the wrong angle. You can't hope to filter every input: that is just a race between two competing factions, and frankly the XSS team have a huge head-start, have entire lists of fun things that you will **never** think to block, and they only need to win *once* for it to count as success; you need to win *every time* for it to count as success.

The correct approach here is to *escape data at output*. In web views this is as simple as:

```
<%: expression %>
```

(instead of `<%= expression %>`, which is unescaped)

In *razor*, escaping is the default, and `@expression` will automatically be escaped unless the expression declares itself to be an `IHtmlString`.

Similarly, your filter mentions SQL; when it comes to SQL, the appropriate approach is to *use parameters*. Don't attempt to sanitize values as a fix to SQL injection (but by all means check that they meet you *business requirements*).

Comment: Im using htmleditorextender and output is scrambled when I used Server.HtmlEncode(output) (as <%: %>), all style is gone.

Answer (score -1):

If you use c# (.net) you could just use

```
string input = @"Injection protection test:
<script> alert('fail'); 
</script> 
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<%= Server.Rewrite( ....) %>"

string[] shouldNotContain=
{
    "sql",
    "<%=",
    "script"
};

if(shouldNotContain.Any(input.Contains)
{
   //The imput contains one or more of the keywords above
}
else
{
    //The string is fine
}
```